# Dell PowerEdge 2009 reports: No boot device available

Tags: boot, dell-poweredge

I accidentally swapped the hard drives and when it restarted it said no boot device available. Please help.

I already tried - clean the RAM and and put it back it doesn't work.

Comment: Open up the system BIOS and check the boot sequence. Make sure the device with the MBR/boot sector on it is the primary boot device.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have RAID or something there, but I think your problem is caused due to the fact that the disk with boot records is on a different position now, and the BIOS is trying to boot from the former position.

Either re-swap the disk like they where before, or change your Boot Order Settings at BIOS.

Maybe you disks are not correctly plugged in, thus you BIOS is unable to locate them. Make sure your server is detecting the disks while checking your BIOS settings.